# Размещение иконок по центру с заданным интервалом

Tags: html, css

Требуется разместить иконки как на скрине

[image: Da]

[image: Net]

Расстояние между иконками `12px`, справа и слева от обозначенных границ одинаковое расстояние

Пытался сделать через `justify-content: space-evenly/space-around`, но тогда если количество иконок будет 3, то расстояние между ними будет НЕ `12px`

Догадываюсь, что нужно решать через псевдо-элементы или тп., но пока что даже не знаю с чего начать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для современных браузеров:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  gap: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

i {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
```

Чуть постарее:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

i {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

i + i {
  margin-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
```

Совсем старых:

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

i + i {
  margin-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Было глупо с моей стороны забывать про `gap` и говорить про псевдо-селекторы